# How can array of arrays be used to store string of variable length in C language?

Tags: c

The following is my code

```
int main(){
   char *movies[500];
   int i=0;

   while(*(movies[i])!='$'){
        scanf("%s",(movies[i]));
        i++;  
   }
}
```

The output is a segmentation fault. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Your `while` loop is testing `movies[i]` before it reads anything into it. It should probably be a `do-while` loop so it tests _after_ reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't have an array of arrays; you have an array of pointers. When you do that, you must allocate the individual strings as you go. If you had an array of arrays, you would be declaring it like this:

```
char movies[500][500]; // <<== Not recommended
```

However, your approach is more economical in terms of memory.

Second, your exit condition (user enters `$` for the first character of the movie name) will never be true, because you always check the value *before* `movies[i]` has been populated.

Here is how you can fix this:

```
char buf[500];
int count = 0;
for (;;) {
    scanf("%s", buf);
    // Check exit condition here
    if (buf[0] == '$') {
        break;
    }
    // Make a copy
    movies[count] = malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
    strcpy(movies[count++], buf);
}
...
// Don't forget to free the strings that you allocated
for (int i = 0 ; i != count ; i++) {
    free(movies[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
movies[i] = malloc(<size>);
```

Allocate memory to each pointer before writing something to it.

Your pointers `movies[i]` doesn't point to any valid memory location and you try to write to it which will lead to undefined behavior hence the crash.

Once done using the memory `free()` it accordingly

Comment: why cant i use a do while loop as in something like  and doesn't char *movies[500] automatically allocate space 
       char *movies[500];
       int i=0;
       
     do{
            scanf("%s",(movies[i]));
              
     }while(*(movies[i++])!='$');

Comment: @AdityaSharma Yes the point is you need to allocate memory to your pointers what you have `char *movies[500]` is array of pointers and for each pointer you need to allocate memory

Comment: Then what is the use of it.I could directly use char movies[500][500];

Comment: @AdityaSharma There are 2 segments stack and heap. Dynamically you can allocate memory on heap using array of pointers and as and when needed . If you allocate memory on stack by creating an 2D array then there might be memory allocated but not used

Comment: when i do movies=(int *)malloc(<size>);.It gives a warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
              movies[i] =(int*) malloc(100);    .why so??

Comment: @AdityaSharma You should do `movies[i] = malloc(100)` no need to cast `malloc()` if this as answered your question mark it as answered